# Mount VHD/VHDX disk image with Linux

Tags: linux, mount, vhd

How do you mount a `.vhd`/`.vhdx` within Linux, as I tried the following on a Raspberry Pi:

```bash
guestmount --add "MYDISK.vhdx" --inspector --ro "/media/pi/MYDISK"
```

- Log:

  ```bash
  guestmount --add MYDISK.vhdx --inspector --ro /media/pi/MYDISK/
  libguestfs: trace: set_verbose true
  libguestfs: trace: set_verbose = 0
  libguestfs: create: flags = 0, handle = 0x1ac5c78, program = guestmount
  libguestfs: trace: set_recovery_proc false
  libguestfs: trace: set_recovery_proc = 0
  libguestfs: trace: add_drive "MYDISK.vhdx" "readonly:true"
  libguestfs: creating COW overlay to protect original drive content
  libguestfs: trace: get_tmpdir
  libguestfs: trace: get_tmpdir = "/tmp"
  libguestfs: trace: disk_create "/tmp/libguestfsdUvGee/overlay1" "qcow2" -1 "backingfile:/media/pi/BACKUP/ARCHIVES/MYDISK.vhdx"
  libguestfs: command: run: qemu-img
  libguestfs: command: run: \ create
  libguestfs: command: run: \ -f qcow2
  libguestfs: command: run: \ -o backing_file=/media/pi/BACKUP/ARCHIVES/MYDISK.vhdx
  libguestfs: command: run: \ /tmp/libguestfsdUvGee/overlay1
  Formatting '/tmp/libguestfsdUvGee/overlay1', fmt=qcow2 size=1099511627776 backing_file=/media/pi/BACKUP/ARCHIVES/MYDISK.vhdx encryption=off cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
  libguestfs: trace: disk_create = 0
  libguestfs: trace: add_drive = 0
  libguestfs: trace: launch
  libguestfs: trace: version
  libguestfs: trace: version = <struct guestfs_version = major: 1, minor: 34, release: 6, extra: , >
  libguestfs: trace: get_backend
  libguestfs: trace: get_backend = "direct"
  libguestfs: launch: program=guestmount
  libguestfs: launch: version=1.34.6
  libguestfs: launch: backend registered: unix
  libguestfs: launch: backend registered: uml
  libguestfs: launch: backend registered: libvirt
  libguestfs: launch: backend registered: direct
  libguestfs: launch: backend=direct
  libguestfs: launch: tmpdir=/tmp/libguestfsdUvGee
  libguestfs: launch: umask=0022
  libguestfs: launch: euid=1000
  libguestfs: is_openable: /dev/kvm: No such file or directory
  libguestfs: trace: get_backend_setting "force_tcg"
  libguestfs: trace: get_backend_setting = NULL (error)
  libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir
  libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir = "/var/tmp"
  libguestfs: begin building supermin appliance
  libguestfs: run supermin
  libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/supermin
  libguestfs: command: run: \ --build
  libguestfs: command: run: \ --verbose
  libguestfs: command: run: \ --if-newer
  libguestfs: command: run: \ --lock /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/lock
  libguestfs: command: run: \ --copy-kernel
  libguestfs: command: run: \ -f ext2
  libguestfs: command: run: \ --host-cpu arm
  libguestfs: command: run: \ /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d
  libguestfs: command: run: \ -o /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d
  supermin: version: 5.1.17
  supermin: package handler: debian/dpkg
  supermin: acquiring lock on /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/lock
  supermin: build: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d
  supermin: reading the supermin appliance
  supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/base.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
  supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/daemon.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
  supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/excludefiles type uncompressed excludefiles
  supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/hostfiles type uncompressed hostfiles
  supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/init.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
  supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/packages type uncompressed packages
  supermin: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-hfsplus: unknown file type in supermin directory
  libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1, see debug messages above
  libguestfs: trace: launch = -1 (error)
  libguestfs: trace: close
  libguestfs: closing guestfs handle 0x1ac5c78 (state 0)
  libguestfs: command: run: rm
  libguestfs: command: run: \ -rf /tmp/libguestfsdUvGee
  ```

Comment: What filesystem are you trying to access? What is the output of `file /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-hfsplus`?

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, did you try a web search for [How do you mount VHD/VHDX within Linux](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+do+you+mount+VHD%2FVHDX+within+Linux&atb=v185-1&ia=web)? **=]**